# PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've updated my rails app from SQLite to postgres and I'm getting the following error when I try to add a new product stock:

```
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  insert or update on table "stocks" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_6d8dd2a287"
DETAIL:  Key (sku)=(16819) is not present in table "products".
: INSERT INTO "stocks" ("store_code", "sku", "quantity", "date", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"
```

**Store.rb**

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stocks, -> { group(:sku) }, foreign_key: :store_code, primary_key: :store_code
  has_many :products, through: :stocks
end
```

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stocks, -> { group(:store_code) }, foreign_key: :sku, primary_key: :sku 
  has_many :stores, through: :stocks
end
```

**Stock.rb**

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :store, primary_key: :store_code, foreign_key: :store_code, class_name: 'Store'
  belongs_to :product, primary_key: :sku, foreign_key: :sku, class_name: 'Product'
end
```

My migrations are:

```
class CreateStores < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :stores do |t|
      t.integer :store_code, null: false
      t.string :name
      t.string :address

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :stores, :store_code, unique: true
  end
end

class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.integer :sku, null: false
      t.string :product_type
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :price, precision: 15, scale: 2
      t.integer :volume
      t.decimal :abv, precision: 3, scale: 1
      t.integer :sweetness
      t.string :style
      t.string :country
      t.string :region
      t.integer :year
      t.text :notes

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :products, :sku, unique: true
  end
end

class CreateStocks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :stocks do |t|
      t.integer :store_code, index: true
      t.integer :sku, index: true
      t.integer :quantity
      t.date :date, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :stocks, :stores, column: :store_code
    add_foreign_key :stocks, :products, column: :sku
  end
end
```

The error is saying that the sku is not in the products table but it is. If I run a SQL query on that sku on the products table it returns one row.

What have I got wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting an `sku` of `16819` from? How specifically do you know that it is valid? Are you sure you're running the SQL query against the same database?

Comment: That sku is from a product that I added myself. It is in the db because I can retrieve it with `Product.find_by(sku: 16819)`

Comment: Can you create a `Stock` using the SKU from the same console where `Product.find_by(sku: 16819)` works?

Comment: No. I can't create a new Stock in any way since switching to postgres. Worked in SQLite though

Comment: Connect to your database with `psql` from the command line and see what `select * from products where sku 16819;` says.

Comment: It returns one row from the products table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the problem was fixed by restarting and resetting everything. I restarted postgres, exited the server and console, ran `rake db:migrate:reset` and now I can insert stocks with no issues.

Comment: Disclaimer doing this `db:migrate:reset` drops your database, creates a new one and runs migrate.